# How to delete just one attribute from dynamo Db row without deleting the whole row?

Tags: kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

In a table abc

```
1. A   B    C
2. 1    2     3
3. 4    5     6
4. 7    8     9
```

Suppose From the above table I only want to remove value `6` from column `C` row `3` without deleting any other value in the row how do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the UpdateItem API with an update expression of `REMOVE C`. See [Deleting Attributes from an Item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE).

Answer (score 0):

When using updateItem, just as you have SET in the update expression to modify an attribute, there is REMOVE to delete a particular attribute from an item. Please refer [AWS documentation for REMOVE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE). If you are looking for something in Kotlin, [this](https://github.com/floodfx/aws-dynamodb-getting-started-guide-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/floodfx/LearnDynamo.kt) might help too.

But most importantly make sure that the particular attribute you are trying to remove has no constraints on deleting it (not null properties or it might need some value by default). Hope this helps Varsha.